# Does iterable list change by operations?

Tags: java, list, iterator

I have my own encoded iterable class and I created an iterable list in the demo section.These methods is included in my class.

```
public void add(E e);
public Node<E> next();
public void hasNext();
public Node<E> previous();
```

And here is operations on my list to iterate on.

```
list.add("2");
list.add("11");
list.add("8");
list.add("9");
list.add("20");

//list is 2 -- 11 -- 8 -- 9 -- 20
```

Now, we are having an iterable list.

```
OwnIterator ite = list.ownIterator();
```

Then, I am going ahead on the list and have some operation. (Here cursor points out 0. index)

```
ite.next(); // by this method cursor points out the element at the index 1
ite.next(); // cursor shifts to 2. index
ite.add("7");

//list is 2 -- 11 -- 7 -- 8 -- 9 -- 20 // when we call next() after add(), it returns 8 not 7;
```

1- Should it return 7 instead of 8 ?

2- What if I call previous() when cursor pointing 8? Does it return 7 or 11? The main problem of mine here is if the operations on iterable list affect the current iterable list? Is it always

2 -- 11 -- 8 -- 9 -- 20

or new added elements take place in the iterable list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, since you are implementing your own iterator, you can do whatever makes sense to you.

If you wish your iterator to fit the contract of `java.util.ListIterator` (you will have to choose `ListIterator`, since `java.util.Iterator` has unspecified behavior when adding elements while iterating over the collection), you can follow this logic:

> **void java.util.ListIterator.add(E e)**
>
> Inserts the specified element into the list (optional operation). The element is inserted immediately before the element that would be returned by next, if any, and after the element that would be returned by previous, if any. (If the list contains no elements, the new element becomes the sole element on the list.) The new element is inserted before the implicit cursor: a subsequent call to next would be unaffected, and a subsequent call to previous would return the new element. (This call increases by one the value that would be returned by a call to nextIndex or previousIndex.)